# Issues again with SQL query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Once again...with little knowledge I'm forced to post idiotic questions on this and once again help and hints will be much appreciated.

Situation - List the first and last name of all movie stars that appeared in more than two films that were nominated for at least two Academy Awards and have an average critic rating of 4 or less.

..And once again this code is wrong as I'm having to join 3 tables (I'm barely making it through with joining 2) however this is as close of an understanding as my knowledge brings me.

```
    SELECT STAR.starFirstName, STAR.starLastName
    FROM (STAR INNER JOIN MOVSTAR ON STAR.starID=MOVSTAR.starID)
    INNER JOIN MOVIE ON MOVSTAR.mvID=MOVIE.mvID)
    WHERE MOVIE.noms >=2
    AND critRate <4;
```

Comment: `critRate <=4` will give you  `average critic rating of 4 or less.` what you are getting right now ?

Comment: As much as I hate to say this, the critRate part I believe is correct but on a whole this code is incorrect..was hoping for recommendations on how to fix this.

Comment: Probably not important for such a basic query, but you should always add the tag for your DBMS. Postgres, Oracle, DB2, ...

Comment: Yes, will take note of that next time. Just that this occasion is extremely urgent for me as everything is due in less than 15hours for me. I've yet to sleep since Friday as well...sigh

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    SELECT STAR.starFirstName, STAR.starLastName
    FROM STAR
          JOIN MOVSTAR 
               ON STAR.starID  = MOVSTAR.starID
          JOIN MOVIE 
               ON MOVSTAR.mvID = MOVIE.mvID
    WHERE MOVIE.noms >= 2
    AND critRate <= 4
```

Comment: Gives me the original error code of "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Comment: make sure STAR, MOVSTAR, and MOVIE are tables

Comment: Yes, they're tables for sure. STAR contains the MOVIESTARS mentioned in the sentence, MOVSTAR contains MovieID and StarID to show which stars appeared in which movies and the table MOVIE displays the list of Movies.

Comment: does STAR contains starID?

Comment: Yes, STAR contains starID also MOVIE contains mvID while MOVSTAR contains both to show which star appeared in which movie.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` to get average rating for an actor. `HAVING` clause is used for conditions on aggregate functions.

```
SELECT STAR.starFirstName, STAR.starLastName
FROM STAR
    INNER JOIN MOVSTAR ON STAR.starID = MOVSTAR.starID
    INNER JOIN MOVIE ON MOVSTAR.mvID = MOVIE.mvID
WHERE MOVIE.noms >= 2
GROUP BY STAR.starFirstName, STAR.starLastName
HAVING AVG(critRate) < 4
   AND COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Cheers for the help! After playing around with the code I managed to get it working with 


'SELECT STAR.starFirstName, STAR.starLastName
FROM ((STAR INNER JOIN MOVSTAR ON STAR.starID = MOVSTAR.starID)
INNER JOIN MOVIE ON MOVSTAR.mvID = MOVIE.mvID)
WHERE MOVIE.noms>=2
GROUP BY STAR.starFirstName, STAR.starLastName
HAVING AVG(critRate)<4
AND COUNT(*)>=2'

Comment: Great! (Is the optional parentheses your only change? Where those required? Which dbms procuct?)

Comment: Ah, I also relocated "STAR" where you had 
FROM STAR 
           INNER STAR JOIN..etc, etc
I changed it to FROM((STAR INNER..etc, because it seems that your coding doesn't operate on Microsoft Access, but the small changed made it work

Comment: Right, didn't know you were using MS Access.

Comment: Ahaha yea, my bad! But like I said on the comment a fair way up ↑, it was quite urgent for me and I didn't really think about each and every information I could provide, though I'm honestly thankful for your help now I might actually be able to somewhat pass.